# Recovering a polynomial from its zero locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties

[Gathmann's Plane Algebraic Curves](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/curves-2018/curves-2018.pdf)

[image]

I do not understand the last statement of this corollary i.e. The irreducible components of F(but not their multiplicities) can be recovered from V(F). Does this mean that if I am given V(F) for some polynomial F(which is not known) then I can find its irreducible components/irreducible factorisation but without any information about multiplicities? If yes, then how does it follow from the corollary?

[image]

I have attached the relevant definitions and link to Gathmann's notes which I am referring. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's best to look at a few examples. Think about, say, the reducible curve $x^2 y^3 = 0$. Its irreducible components are $x = 0$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am still confused. My question is given V(F) for some unknown F how can we find its irreducible components if the underlying field is algebraically closed? What is it that I am missing here with regards to my understanding of the corollary?In particular, how does your example illustrate this? In fact , I even know that the above corollary is actually Hilbert's Nullstellensatz if you think in terms of correspondence between radical ideals and zariski closed subsets

Comment: The irreducible components can be determined by considering the Zariski topology on the set of points. But before any of that technical stuff just draw a picture of the situation!

Comment: I get your point but we cannot always visualise the zero set to conclude what the irreducible components would be... so in that case what would you do?

Comment: in fact this becomes a problem ,say,in C,the set of complex numbers

Comment: You seem to be fixating on the practical aspects of the "problem" of finding irreducible components. I think that is beside the point. This result is a matter of abstract mathematics. When we say "can be recovered" or "can be found" or "is determined by" we don't always mean that there is a practical procedure for doing so but more simply that there is a certain logical relationship between one piece of information and another.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see...I think I get your point now...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I do not understand the last statement of this corollary i.e. The irreducible components of F(but not their multiplicities) can be recovered from V(F). Does this mean that if I am given V(F) for some polynomial F(which is not known) then I can find its irreducible components/irreducible factorisation but without any information about multiplicities? If yes, then how does it follow from the corollary?"

**Answer:** If $f(x,y):=f_1(x,y)\cdots f_l(x,y)$ with $f_i \in k[x,y]$ an irreducible polynomial for all $i$ and $f_i \neq f_j$ for $i\neq j$, you may for any set of integers $a:=(a_1,..,a_l)$ with $a_i \geq 1$ define $F_a(x,y):=f_1^{a_1}\cdots f_l^{a_l}$ to get a new polynomial. The two polynomials $f,F_a$ have the same zero set:

$$V(f(x,y))=V(F_a(x,y))$$

but they are clearly different polynomials and different as "plane algebraic curves". If $a_i>1$ for some $i$ there is no element $\lambda\in k^*$ with $kf=F_a$. Hence you cannot recover the multiplicities $a_i$ from the zero set $V(F_a)$, since $V(F_a)=V(f)$ for any choice of $a$.

"..in fact this becomes a problem ,say,in C,the set of complex numbers"

**Example:** If $p:=(u,v)$ is a root/zero of $F_a(x,y)$, it follows

$$F_a(u,v)=\prod f_i^{a_i}(u,v)=0$$

is an equality in the field $k$, hence there is an $i$ with $f_i(u,v)=0$. It follows $f(u,v)=0$. Similarly if $f(u,v)=0$ it follows $F(u,v)=0$. This all follows from the fact that $k$ is a field, hence an integral domain: If a product of elements in $k$ is zero, one of the elements must be zero. Or: The zero ideal is a prime ideal.